# Edit link Missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

I was going to edit a post and I just found out that "edit" Is missing from all questions

[image: See?]

Although the [edit link](https://askubuntu.com/posts/100688/edit) works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the edit link has "disappeared" that means that the question has already been edited by another user, and the edit is pending approval by a mod or 2k user. Never fear! The link shall be back shortly!