# no edit button beside flag

Tags: support, answer-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit link Missing](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2444/edit-link-missing)

I found a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108456/error-in-installing-gocr) which is very ugly and improperly formatted so I want to edit it but there is no edit button only link and flag buttons are there !! 
[image]

Is it a bug?

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2444/edit-link-missing