# Why my `edit` facilities blocked?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit link Missing](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2444/edit-link-missing)

I can't edit some of posts. The `edit` is blocked.

[image]

What cause i can't edit the posts?

Comment: add some example links?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled

Comment: @fossfreedom Only I who get the `edit` block, the others aren't blocked.

Comment: @AmithKK In my post, the `edit` is blocked, not missing like [Edit link Missing](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2444/edit-link-missing)

Comment: Do you see anything when you mouseover the edit button?

Comment: Yes, there is `Account is not allowed to suggest edits`. I only ask what is the reasons.

Comment: I think your edits are being rejected sinnce you are trying to use quote blocks instead on code blocks for code. You can put 4 spaces (8 if in a bulleted or numbered list) before the code to render it as so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be several possible reasons for this. But I think, for your particular case, the main reason could be the number of suggested edits got rejected. If you have many suggested edits *rejected*, you will be blocked for submitting more edits.

See this relevant question on [meta stack overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) :  [Why is the edit buttons disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)

You might also want to check this massively helpful post on meta StackOverflow. [Faq for stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)